# How do I rotate this world while retaining my camera's FOV?

Tags: camera, world

I configured a world with nodes in Blender and I'd like to rotate it along the Z axis.

[image: A world displayed through a camera with a high FOV.]

Unfortunately, as soon as I connect a Mapping and Geometry node, my camera's Focal Length and Sensor Size settings no longer affect the image.

[image: My node setup.]

[image: The world without high FOV.]

Is there any way to retain my field of view settings while having the Geometry and Mapping nodes attached?

You can find the .blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18p5L9TDwbmCxH_eBCIL1OVh3pAFZircm/view?usp=sharing)!

Comment: Try texture coordinate -> generated instead of geometry -> position

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to replace the "Geometry" node with a "Texture Coordinate" node!